# asp.net chart series point label font formats

Tags: asp.net, mschart, label, series

I am currently formatting my chart series point series with the code shown below but I don't see any way to change the font for the point label text.
Does anyone know where to access the font attributes for the point labels?

```
'set the series point color dependent on value and retrieve the best & worst values
    Dim bestval As Double = 0.0
    Dim worstval As Double = 0.0
    For Each pt As DataPoint In cht.Series("MonthPL").Points
        'pt.IsValueShownAsLabel = True
        pt.Label = "#VALY{C0}"
        pt.LabelToolTip = "#AXISLABEL 's P/L is #VALY{C0}"
        If pt.YValues(0) < 0 Then
            If pt.YValues(0) < worstval Then worstval = pt.YValues(0)
            pt.Color = Color.Red
            pt.LabelForeColor = Color.Black
        Else
            If pt.YValues(0) > bestval Then bestval = pt.YValues(0)
            pt.Color = Color.DarkGreen
            pt.LabelForeColor = Color.GhostWhite
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You should see it here

```
pt.Font
```

The actual code I use in c# is

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Font
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new font, and use that:

```
Font myFont = new Font(FontFamily.Generic.SansSerif, 14, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Then set the font property of your datapoint to it:

```
pt.font = myFont;
```

Answer (score 0):

add in series tag as Font="Zurich BT, 11pt, style=Bold"

Comment: Can you include a code example, including how to add it to a series? That will help clarify the suggestion and help put it on par with the two existing answers.

Comment: Like this <Series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Product" ChartType="Column"  Font="Zurich BT, 11pt, style=Bold" LabelForeColor="White">
                            </asp:Series>
                        </Series>